# Unable to retrieve security context from within Spring-Jersey

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, jersey

I am trying to retrieve a security context within my spring-jersey bean, however I keep getting Null authentication. When I run the same command from within my spring application it correctly retrieves the current logged in users security context.

The configuration of spring-jersey requires creating a separate servlet to the main spring application, thus the web.xml has two servlet's - one for spring app, second for jersey rest api.

Assuming the problem is related to this, I tried setting the security context sharing mode to global, however I still unable to get the context information from within Jersey.

```
SecurityContextHolder.setStrategyName(SecurityContextHolder.MODE_GLOBAL)
```

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated!

Many thanks,
Nigel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps user is simply not authenticated, because your Jersey requests don't have a session cookie and therefore are not associated with the authenticated user's session?

You may check it by enabling anonymous authentication in Spring Security - you should get anonymous authentication instead of `null` if the guess is right.

Comment: I have anonymous authentication enabled, like you suggested, I would have expected the configured user to show up, but it doesn't in Jersey. However when I am not authenticated in my spring app, the configured user is show instead of null!

I can see your point about session cookies, I am able to retrieve session cookies from my Jersey code using @Context HttpServletRequest req, then retrieving session from there. However SecurityContextHolder is session independent from what I understand (?).

Comment: @Nigel: Yes, it's session independent, but for authenticated users it's populated from the session attributes by Spring Security filters. So, are you Jersey requests processed by the Spring Security filters?

Comment: Thank you for the comment. This clue helped solve my problem, checking how my security filters were configured, I found this line in my spring security configuration  
<pre>  

    <security:intercept-url pattern="/api/**" filters="none" />  
</pre>
Removing this fixed the problem, which effectively disables all spring security filters!  
  
Many thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

@axtavt Thank you for the comment. This clue helped solve my problem, checking how my security filters were configured, I found this line in my spring security configuration

```
<security:intercept-url pattern="/api/**" filters="none" />
```

This line effectively disables all spring security filters, removing this fixed the problem.

Many thanks for your help :)